# How do I Query an excel table to show the amount of duplicate values in a column and the total spend for each one?

Tags: sql, excel

I need to know how I can sql query this excel table so that 3 new columns appear showing: The customer number, the amount of times they have appeared and their total spend.

Please see the original table below:

```
Reciept         Logged              Customer  Spend
------------------------------------------------------
0906660001770   23/07/2014 4:30     A07317    $209.95
0900010001423   16/10/2014 15:16    A07399    $674.98
0900010001424   16/10/2014 15:16    A07399    $10.00
0906660003300   12/12/2014 12:00    A07473    $69.99
0906660002126   15/09/2014 12:46    A07474    $24.99
0906660003395   14/12/2014 14:46    A07474    $379.92
0906660002853   24/11/2014 15:45    A07478    $1,247.94
0906660001105   13/03/2014 14:15    A07538    $554.97
0906660001379   4/05/2014 14:30     A07538    $252.95
0900010000694   6/05/2014 10:48     A07538    $0.00
```

Here is what I need the resulting sql statement to look like:

```
Customer    Count  TotalSpend
------------------------------------------------------
A07317      1      $209.95
A07399      2      $684.98
A07473      1      $69.99
A07474      2      $404.91
A07478      1      $1247.94
A07538      3      $807.92
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

More information can be found at: [Query Excel as relational data](http://exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-relational-data.htm). And the sql query should look like below:

```
SELECT Customer, COUNT(Customer) AS COUNT, SUM(Spend) AS TotalSpend 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY Customer
```